# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Why is this bit of code:

```
    protected bool IsServerPeer(InitRequest initRequest)
    {
        return _subServerCollection.IsServerPeer(initRequest);
    }
```

creating the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: The compiler isn't lying. Find out why the expression being "returned" is not conforming to `bool`; and therein will be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `_subServerCollection.IsServerPeer()` has the return type `void`

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value from `_subServerCollection.IsServerPeer`. It might not returning boolean value. From the error message the above method might have return type `void(nothing returned from the method)`.

Comment: Ah, i was just not digging hard enough. It was just the type misplacment.